# Scrollable child on android is not scrollable when in a ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, react-native

I'm trying to use react-native-webview in a horizontally scrollable ScrollView.

On IOS it's working fine, but on Android it seems that if the user don't scroll in a perfect vertical manner, the scrollView starts to steal all the events which completely blocks scrolling in the webView.

Again, on IOS it works fine

The code looks a little like this

```
<ScrollView
  ref={(c) => {this.scroll = c}}
  onMomentumScrollEnd={this.handleScroll}
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  decelerationRate={0.0}
  directionalLockEnabled
  nestedScrollEnabled
>

   <WebView
     style={ webviewStyle }
     source={{ uri: 'http://www.google.com' }}
     startInLoadingState
   />
   <WebView
     style={ webviewStyle }
     source={{ uri: 'http://www.google.com' }}
     startInLoadingState
   />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an ongoing issue on webview and still not updated yet. You might consider using another webview library such as [Webview Library](https://github.com/iou90/react-native-autoheight-webview#readme)
.Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up using a trick more than a fix which detect a swipe event from the webView and temporarily blocks the swipe on the scrollView which allow for a 'normal' scrolling on a page

It looks a little like that

```
 async pauseSwipe() {

    if (!this.state.swipeDisabled) {
      this.setState({ swipeDisabled: true }, () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({
            swipeDisabled: false,
          })
          }, 1000)
      })
    }
  }
```

```
<WebView
  injectedJavaScript="window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(event));});true;"
  onMessage={event => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.data) {
      this.pauseSwipe()
    }
  }}
/>
```

and this in the scrollView

```
scrollEnabled={!this.state.swipeDisabled}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try with

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{
    flex: 1 
}}>
```

Comment: Yep, I've tried. 
That's actually the webview style, should've mentioned it before

`flex: 1, width: wp('100%'), height: hp('80%')`

Comment: Well actually specifically using `contentContainerStyle={{ flex:1 }}` makes all the childs appear on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

in android, when parent view and child view both can scroll. it will occur scroll conflict.you have to use the `nestedScrollEnabled` and set it true to make the child scroll. the official document says:

**Enables nested scrolling for Android API level 21+. Nested scrolling is supported by default on iOS.**

at the same time, you also have to set the child and parent view a height.

Comment: Yes the scrollview actually has nestedScrollEnabled   and both views have a set height and flex:1

Comment: give the scroll view a Device height, like `Dimensions.get('window').height`, then give the webView height too. not flex.  try it.